# arcpy geoprocessing service with sde database produces no output url

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, web-service, geoprocessing-service, url

I'm trying to use a geoprocessing script to clip some data and return to the user (via url) the path to a zip file with the results of the clip.  I also need to connect to an sde database.  I can get a url to show up if I use shapefiles and but it seems to loose the plot when i use the sde connection (probably because i have to set the workspace to the sde connection and then the server doesn't have a place to write temp files to?!).  It runs okay but doesn't produce any output on the server folders and i do not get a url.  I have pasted the code below (hopefully it shows up ok).  Thanks. ps: I copied a lot of the code from esri's ship and clip example. Also i registered "D:\arcgisserver\directories\service_output" on the server as a folder so it is able to see it.

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os
import traceback
import zipfile

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def zipUpFolder(folder, outZipFile):
    # zip the data
    try:
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outZipFile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipws(unicode(folder), zip, "CONTENTS_ONLY")
        zip.close()
    except RuntimeError:
        # Delete zip file if exists
        if os.path.exists(outZipFile):
            os.unlink(outZipFile)
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outZipFile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED)
        zipws(unicode(folder), zip, "CONTENTS_ONLY")
        zip.close()
        #Message"  Unable to compress zip file contents."
        gp.AddWarning(get_ID_message(86133))
def zipws(path, zip, keep):
    path = os.path.normpath(path)
    # os.walk visits every subdirectory, returning a 3-tuple
    #  of directory name, subdirectories in it, and filenames
    #  in it.
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        # Iterate over every filename
        for file in filenames:
            # Ignore .lock files
            if not file.endswith('.lock'):
                #gp.AddMessage("Adding %s..." % os.path.join(path, dirpath, file))
                try:
                    if keep:
                        zip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file),
                        os.path.join(os.path.basename(path), os.path.join(dirpath, file)[len(path)+len(os.sep):]))
                    else:
                        zip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file),
                        os.path.join(dirpath[len(path):], file))

                except Exception as e:
                    #Message "    Error adding %s: %s"
                    arcpy.AddWarning(get_ID_message(86134) % (file, e[0]))
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(r"D:\arcgisserver\directories\service_scripts", u'db_Conn.sde')
        ws = "D:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\service_output" 
        arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "D:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\service_output"
        outputZipFile = "D:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\service_output\\out.zip"
        zipFolderPath = "D:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\service_output\\output"

        aoi = "455719.332353, 6300257.134719, 499534.419983,6269598.547920"
        serviceDataset="ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_HISTORICAL"

        dsList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Feature")
        for ds in dsList:
            if serviceDataset in ds:
                fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",ds)
                for fc in fcList:
                    featureclass = fc.split(".")[2] 
                    arcpy.AddMessage(fc)

                    exts = []
                    exts = aoi.split(",")
                    extent = arcpy.Extent(exts[0],exts[1],exts[2],exts[3])
                    pts = [arcpy.Point(extent.XMin, extent.YMin),
                    arcpy.Point(extent.XMax, extent.YMin),
                    arcpy.Point(extent.XMax, extent.YMax),
                    arcpy.Point(extent.XMin, extent.YMax)]
                    array = arcpy.Array(items=pts)
                    poly = arcpy.Polygon(array)

                    sr = arcpy.SpatialReference()
                    sr.factoryCode = 26912
                    sr.create()
                    poly = arcpy.Polygon(array,sr)  

                    tmp_poly = os.path.join(ws, "polygon.shp")
                    tmp_orig = os.path.join(ws, "to_clip.shp")
                    outputpath = os.path.join(zipFolderPath, fc.split(".")[2]+".shp")

                    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(poly, "D:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\service_output\\tmp_poly.shp")#tmp_poly)
                    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, tmp_poly, outputpath)

        zipUpFolder(zipFolderPath, outputZipFile)

        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, outputZipFile)
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace) 

    except:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
        pymsg = "ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
                unicode(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + unicode(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
```